# Как фрагменту понять что он ушел “на паузу”? (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Как фрагменту понять что он пошел “на паузу”? Имеется в виду, что его "накрыл" другой фрагмент к примеру. По факту фрагмент не имеет метода onPause(), но все же как это можно отследить? Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Почему не имеет onPause? А так ещё есть `setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` - вызывается при смене видимости. Опишите подробнее для чего вам это нужно и вообще задачу - может вы её не тем способом решить пытаетесь

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо за ответ. Сначала прочитал в одном источнике, что нету такого метода, вот и указал а потом открыл сайте developer android - оказывается есть.
Это вопрос на курсах задали, я его дословно и описал. 2 варианта лучше, чем один))

Answer (score 4):

[Жизненный цикл фрагментов](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating) схож с жизненным циклом активностей. У фрагментов тоже есть метод `onPause()`, который можно переопределить, чтобы отслеживать состояние постановки на паузу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]